# vue.js - Unable to reference router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

At some point between editing my code I had at least a portion of this working but of course did not commit before those times.

project: https://github.com/Ampix0/ticker-for-robinhood;

Code issue: https://github.com/Ampix0/ticker-for-robinhood/blob/master/app/src/renderer/components/LoginPageView.vue

On line 26 you can see the login function, when it completes it is supposed to route to the next page, passing along the access token.

Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$router' of undefined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (renderer.js:1574), <anonymous>:18:21)
```

Comment: You lost your `this` context. There's dozens of answers to how to fix this here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically is the same problem which I just answered a few days ago: [Show error message in Vue js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43516440/show-error-message-in-vue-js/43516925#43516925)

Because you lost the `this` reference in `.then(function (response) {..`

Use arrow functions can solve this easily:

```
.then((response) => {
    this.$router.push({
        name: 'home-page',
        params: {
            authKey: response.data.token
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: I thought it would be something like this. Thank you!